# Display geotiff images with qt

Tags: c++, qt, geotiff

I am currently trying to make a graphical interface to a script projecting DSMs (geotiff file) on images. I thought it was a good idea to display both image and DSM before making some computations.
Unfortunately, even if there is no problem to display the image, I have the following error while trying to display the DSM:

```
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 42112 (0xa480) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, foo: unknown field with tag 42113 (0xa481) encountered.
foo: Sorry, can not handle images with 32-bit samples.
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
```

Here is what I am currently trying:

```
QString s1 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open a DSM", "/home", "Images (*.png *.xpm *.jpg *.tif *.tiff)");
ui->DSMPath->setText(s1);
QPixmap dispdsm(s1);
int w = ui->DSMDisplay->width();
int h = ui->DSMDisplay->height();
ui->DSMDisplay->setPixmap(dispdsm.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

I searched on the internet, but it seems that there is no solution yet.

I precise that I am working on Ubuntu with QT and OpenCV and Magick++ libraries.

Can someone please help me ?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "display the DSM"?  A DSM might be stored as a GeoTIFF, but it isn't an image, which is likely why you're getting the error messages.

Comment: Well, as it is stored as a .tif image and I can see it with every image viewer (black and white, 1 channel), I thought it would be displayable as a normal image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt simply doesn't support the images in the format that you're using. You'd need to use your own `QImageIOHandler` wrapper for libgeotiff.

Answer (score 1):

Kuba Ober is right, but for those who wants to display geotiff images without defining there own `QImageIOHandler` and who uses OpenCV, you can just load your geotiff image as an OpenCV matrix and convert it to a QImage.

Here is the conversion in my case:

```
QImage image= QImage((uchar*) dsm.data, dsm.cols, dsm.rows, dsm.step, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
QPixmap dispdsm = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
```

Where `dsm` in my OpenCV matrix, and `dispdsm` the displayable version of it.